# from google.cloud import speech lib not exist

Tags: gcloud

I have installed google SDK and also google-cloud-speech for python through pip. But when I type "from google.cloud import speech", it is not recognizing the library. Please help.

Comment: Did you install the client library? Can you post the error message?

Comment: To install library     pip install --upgrade google-cloud-speech

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace? Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Install the client library

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-speech
```